# How to compare two lists of strings to find identical strings

Tags: .net, vb.net, string, list

I have two lists of strings that contain a set of names, what I want to know is how can I compare these two lists to find identical names and then write an if statement which performs actions based on the comparison.

List 1:
Philip
Bob
Michael

List 2:
James
Peter
Bob

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the many linq extensions is `Intersect` which returns the elements common to both:

```
Dim names1 = {"Philip", "Bob", "Michael"}
Dim names2 = {"James", "Ziggy", "Bob", "Hoover"}

Dim commonNames = names1.Intersect(names2).ToArray()
For Each n As String In commonNames
    Console.WriteLine(n)
Next
```

Output:

> Bob

There are a bunch of these, you can type `.` (dot) and browse them thru Intellisense and read the 1-liner of what they do and at least become aware they exist.

Answer (score 1):

First time writing VB. You can use the nested loops below to find an identical. If you want case to matter, replace equalsIgnoreCase with just equals

```
    Dim list1() as String ={"name1","name2"}
    Dim list2() as String ={"name3","name2"}
    For Each str as String In list1
        For Each names as String In list2
          If String.Compare(str,names) = 0 Then
           Console.WriteLine(str+" "+names)
          End If
        Next names
    Next str
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be helpful

```
    lstNew = lstOne.Intersect(lstTwo, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    PrintList(lstNew)

    Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

     Private Sub PrintList(ByVal str As IEnumerable(Of String))
     For Each s In str
     Console.WriteLine(s)
     Next s
     Console.WriteLine("-------------")
```

Reference
http://www.devcurry.com/2010/07/list-common-elements-between-two-list.html?m=1

Answer (score 0):

```
    Dim names1 = {"Philip", "Ziggy", "Bob", "Michael", "James"}
    Dim names2 = {"James", "Ziggy", "Bob", "Michael", "Hoover"}

    Dim commonNames = names1.Intersect(names2).ToArray()
    Dim Match As String = ""
    Dim NumberOfMatches = 0

    For Each n As String In commonNames
        Match += n.ToString + " "
        NumberOfMatches += 1
    Next

    TextBox1.Text = Match
    TextBox2.Text = NumberOfMatches
```

Output will contain all of the identical names & Number of Matches:
Ziggy Bob Michael James &
4